# Apache Shiro - Browser URL only works when using the website to navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, shiro

I'm using Java (maven) for the backend and Angular 2 for the frontend with Shiro.  I can navigate to different URLs as long as I use the website.  Entering the URL manually causes a 404 error.

I'm not sure if the problem is with Angular (since it uses a single index.html page) or it's with the `[URL]` section in shiro.ini.

Leaving the `[URL]` section empty or adding `/index.html = anon` continues to cause the same problem.

Also, using `authc` redirects me to login.jsp.

How can I allow access to every route regardless of the users status/role?

Comment: This is a common issue, the main problem is your server routing the requests. I don't know how Shiro works, but try to redirect the routes that you use for your angular app inside of your backend server to return always your index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a server side issue (not Shiro).  The first couple things to check is if you are using HTML5 mode (it sounds like it based on your question).  If you are you MUST handle the the angular routes (and forward them to your index.html page)

You can use the [rewrite servlet](http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) to handle this. Here is one [example of this](https://github.com/bdemers/shiro-angular-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stormpath/tutorial/rewrite/RewriteServletConfigProvider.java#L28-L49).

There are a few different ways to handle forwarding, you could could also just write a simple servlet or filter.

Comment: I ran the rewrite servlet but there was some incompatibility issues because my project runs on an older version of Java.  I ended up using  a [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html).  This places a # after the project name to differentiate its children.  I believe your answer will also work.  I will upvote if you could include a simple servlet/filter example.